# How to fix 'unrecognised token' when executing calling db.delete

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I use SQLite to store and retrieve data for an android app. I created a method that deletes entries to the table by deleting their primary key which is a UUID. However when I call my .delete command I am getting an unreconginized token.

(Current mindset) The database expects to pinpoint a string where as the entry to delete is pointed to using c.getId() which returns a UUID and not a string. But I am not sure how to convert it or perhaps it is a syntax problem in the expression.

//CheckInList.java

```
public class CheckInList {
    private static CheckInList sCheckInList;
    private Context mContext;
    public SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
...
//PROBLEM METHOD v
public void deleteCheckIn(CheckIn c) {
        mDataBase.delete(DATABASE_NAME,  CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + "=" + c.getId(), null);
    }
...
```

///CheckInBaseHelper

```
public class CheckInBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "checkinBase.db";

    public CheckInBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create TABLE " + CheckInTable.NAME + "(" +
                " _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.PLACE + ", " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.DETAILS + ", " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.DATE + ", " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.LATITUDE + ", " +
                CheckInTable.Cols.LONGITUDE +
                ")"
        );
    }
```

///CheckInCursorWrapper

```
public class CheckInCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {
    public CheckInCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public CheckIn getCheckIn() {
        String uuidString = getString(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.UUID));
        String title = getString(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.TITLE));
        String place = getString(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.PLACE));
        String details = getString(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.DETAILS));
        long date = getInt(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.DATE));
        Double latitude = getDouble(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.LATITUDE));
        Double longitude = getDouble(getColumnIndex(CheckInTable.Cols.LONGITUDE));

        CheckIn checkin = new CheckIn(UUID.fromString(uuidString));
        checkin.setTitle(title);
        checkin.setPlace(place);
        checkin.setDetails(details);
        checkin.setDate(new Date(date));
        checkin.setLatitude(latitude);
        checkin.setLongitude(longitude);

        return checkin;
    }
}
```

The method is intended to remove a checkin from the database by identifying each entry with its ID.

SQLiteExceptions: `unrecognized token: "7ac5"`

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "7ac5" (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE FROM checkinBase.db WHERE uuid=d21a141d-7ac5-487b-a5af-6eae0825ac37`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue of an unrecognised token you have another issue that you would encounter. The issues are :-

- a) You delete from a TABLE **not the database**, which may (WILL) have multiple tables.
- b) you need to enclose a String in single quotes, that is use uuid='d21a141d-7ac5-487b-a5af-6eae0825ac37'. You could change ......`+ "=" + c.getId()` to ......`+ "='" + c.getId() + "'"`.

However, it is recommended that values are bound (typically you use a **`?`** place-holder which is replaced with the value, it being suitably enclosed (e.g. the single quotes added)), thus protecting against SQL injection.

A complete fix would be to change :-

```
public void deleteCheckIn(CheckIn c) {
    mDataBase.delete(DATABASE_NAME,  CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + "=" + c.getId(), null);
}
```

to

```
public int deleteCheckIn(CheckIn c) {
    return mDataBase.delete(CheckInTable.NAME,  CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + "=?", new String[]{c.getId()});
}
```

The above will :-

- Use the table instead of the database, eliminating the table not found exception that was about to happen.
- correct the unrecognised token.
- protect against SQL injection.
- return the number of rows that were deleted, which may be useful to know (e.g. if 0 no rows were deleted).

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike! I've replaced the code as you suggested yet it has just returned this: error: incompatible types: UUID cannot be converted to String

Comment: @h0pper then you need to retrieve a suitable value or perhaps values from the CheckIn class, it may be that c.getId().toString() is suitable, although the value should reflect how you store the value so you basically need to reverse that.